# Difference between Sharepoint Server & Sharepoint Foundation

Tags: 2010, installation, edition

What is the difference between Sharepoint Server & Foundation. To what I know, Sharepoint foundation is one of the editions other being Standard & Enterprise (as seen here http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx).

I also know that Sharepoint Foundation is a free tool with basic features as being its limitations with Server being a full feature paid versions. Correct me if I'm wrong or missing something.

Answer (score 6):

Features missing in Foundation:

- Business Intelligence
- Audience Targeting
- Improved Governance
- Secure Store Service
- Web Analytics
- Enterprise Wikis
- Tag Clouds & Profiles

for a detailed comparison check [this](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-hosting/2010/features/foundation-vs-server.asp) helpful link.

Comment: While that link points to something very helpful - it would be more useful if some context is provided along with the link - should the link break. See here regarding 'Provide context for links' - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score 5):

You may want to list out the requirements of your applications and then look into the numerous features of the SharePoint 2010 editions here - [Foundation/Standard/Enterprise](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx).

The Foundation edition is not "free" - it is added onto a Windows Server or Win7/Vista (all OS are paid for). SharePoint deployment on Win7/Vista is for development purposes only (not for production deployment). More on it here - [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx).  All editions have an additional hardware requirement of 64-bit operating systems (& SQL Server).

Technically, the primary differences between the editions are with the various service applications & their available features, for e.g., Business Connectivity Services, Managed Metadata, Search, User Profile, Office applications, PerformancePoint (BI) and others. See this diagram for more details regarding - [SharePoint Services (top right corner table lists services features & editions).](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=167090)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the nice edition comparision matrix :

- [SHAREPOINT FOUNDATION VS. SHAREPOINT SERVER](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-foundation-server/)